# Count total results from another table minus number from original table column based on condition

Tags: mysql

I fear i have been away from mysql too long and I'm going down a rabbit hole.

client_sessions

```
id      cid      sessions      date
------------------------------------------
1       102          5       01/07/2017
2       102          3       01/08/2017
3       141          5       29/07/2017
```

User 102 had 5 sessions available from 01/07/2017 id - 1
User 102 had 3 sessions available from 01/08/2017 id - 2

client_sessions_history

```
id      sid      date
----------------------------
1       1      03/07/2017
2       1      07/07/2017
3       1      14/07/2017
4       1      21/07/2017
5       1      27/07/2017
6       2      01/08/2017
```

sid is the id from client_sessions, there are 5 here for 1
and 1 here from 2.

Result I want is:

```
date            remaining
-----------------------------
01/07/2017          0
01/08/2017          2
```

which would be the sessions from client_sessions unique by date minus the total sessions in client_sessions_history unique by the sid

I've tried the following but I have been going around in circles.

```
select a.sessions, a.id, (select count(distinct sid) from client_sessions_history where b.sid = a.id) as remaining from client_sessions as a, client_sessions_history as b where a.cid = 102
```

Basically I would like to get the remaining total for cid 102

Comment: I don't understand how you arrive at your expected output.  Could you explain the logic there?

Comment: Sorry, little tired today I have edited the question, it may make more sense thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create table/insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE client_sessions
    (`id` INT, `cid` INT, `sessions` INT, `date` VARCHAR(10))
;

INSERT INTO client_sessions
    (`id`, `cid`, `sessions`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 102, 5, '01/07/2017'),
    (2, 102, 3, '01/08/2017'),
    (3, 141, 5, '29/07/2017')
;


CREATE TABLE client_sessions_history
    (`id` INT, `sid` INT, `date` VARCHAR(10))
;

INSERT INTO client_sessions_history
    (`id`, `sid`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '03/07/2017'),
    (2, 1, '07/07/2017'),
    (3, 1, '14/07/2017'),
    (4, 1, '21/07/2017'),
    (5, 1, '27/07/2017'),
    (6, 2, '01/08/2017')
;
```

You need to create a delivered table where you COUNT the client history sessions.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    client_sessions.date
 , (client_sessions.sessions - client_sessions_grouped.client_sessions_history_sid_count) AS remaining
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
      client_sessions.id
    , COUNT(client_sessions_history.sid) AS client_sessions_history_sid_count
   FROM 
    client_sessions
   INNER JOIN 
     client_sessions_history
   ON
     client_sessions.id =  client_sessions_history.sid 
   GROUP BY
    client_sessions.id 
) 
 AS
   client_sessions_grouped
INNER JOIN
  client_sessions
ON
  client_sessions.id = client_sessions_grouped.id

WHERE
  client_sessions.cid = 102
```

**Result**

```
date        remaining  
----------  -----------
01/07/2017            0
01/08/2017            2
```

Answer (score 0):

could be you need  a count distinct and group by

```
  select month(date), count(a.distinct sid)
  from client_sessions_history  a 
  inner join client_sessions b on a.sid = b.id
  where b.cid= 102
  group by  month(date)
```

Comment: what is the function mount?

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
SELECT 
  date , 
  (sessions - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM client_sessions_history WHERE sid = client_sessions.id )) AS remaining

FROM client_sessions   
WHERE cid = 102
```